# Foliations of spheres

Tags: vector-bundles, spheres, foliations

Reading a paper, I came across the statement that there are no transversely orientable codimension-one foliations on even dimensional spheres $\mathbb{S}^{2n}$. Could anyone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thurston has shown that if a closed manifold has a codimension one foliation, its Euler characteristic is zero. But the Euler number of the $2n$-sphere is $2$.

Existence of Codimension-One Foliations

W. P. Thurston

Annals of Mathematics

Second Series, Vol. 104, No. 2 (Sep., 1976), pp. 249-268

Answer (score 4):

If I am not misunderstanding, even dimensional spheres don't have any foliations where the leaves have positive dimension, except the trivial case where the whole sphere is a leaf.

To see this, suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a foliation of $S^{2n}$ and let $\mathcal{V}\subseteq TS^{2n}$ denote the sub-bundle of $TS^{2n}$ consisting of vectors tangent to leaves in $\mathcal{F}$.

Since vector sub-bundles always have complements, we get a decomposition $TS^{2n} = \mathcal{V}\oplus \mathcal{V}'$.

Now, compute the Euler class.  We have $e(TS^{2n}) = 2\in H^{2n}(S^{2n})$, as Tsemo mentions, so $2 = e(\mathcal{V})\cup e(\mathcal{V}')$.  Since $H^k(S^{2n})$ is non-trivial only when $k = 0$ or $2n$, it follows that $\mathcal{V}$ has rank $0$ or $2n$.  That is, the leaves are either points, or full dimension.

Comment: it seems like this is related to the non-existence of nonvanishing vector fields on spheres.

Comment: The complementary sub-bundle of the codim 1 foliation will be a line bundle.  This is a priori a bit weaker than a non-vanishing vector field:  Taking the span of a non-vanishing vector field gives a line bundle, but to go from a line bundle to a non-vanishing vector field you have to make a consistent choice of non-zero element from each line.  (That said, on a simply connected manifold $M$, the two notions agree: a line minus $0$ deformation retracts to $\{1,-1\}$.  Create a manifold $N$ consisting of points $(p, \pm 1)$ where $p\in M$.  There is a natural covering $N\rightarrow M$....

Comment: If $M$ is simply connected, then $N$ must be disconnected.  This tells you can make the consistent choice of $(p,1)$ everywhere.).  Also, how is life, James?

Comment: Interesting, nice answer. Life is busy but good. Our fifth (Benjamin) is about 6 weeks old. I'm teaching classes I generally enjoy. How about you ?

Comment: Great on my end, but I only have 3 kids - I can't imagine 5!  Teaching (and some research) is also quite rewarding!

Comment: it might be a stupid question, but i'll make it anyways: the Euler class isn't defined just for vector bundles of even rank?

Comment: @Eduardo:  See the comments to this MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/196562/what-is-obstructing-two-stably-isomorphic-vector-bundles-from-being-isomorphic.  The short version is that the Euler class is defined for any orientable$^*$ vector bundle, but is necessarily $2$-torsion if the bundle has odd rank.  So, for any manifold with no $2$-torsion in its cohomology ring, the Euler class of an odd rank bundle must be trivial.  * As even dimensional spheres are $1$-connected, the first Stiefel-Whitney class of any vector bundle is $0$, so every vector bundle is orientable.

Comment: Use induction, after one kid, it's the same. Research sounds nice, I haven't done as much as I'd like just yet. Seems like there is always something more to teach... Glad you're enjoying life over there, maybe I'll run into you at a conference some time. Let me know if your school hosts something neat.